# Add a button on top of imageview similar to iPhone profile setting page

Tags: objective-c, image, button, label

I want to add a button over an image similar to iPhone profile setting page. Below I have attached the screenshot. I want to add the edit button over a circular image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA0hn.png

Comment: Is there a question you would like people to answer?  If so, could you edit your post to include it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the image and the button in a vertical `UIStackView`.
2. Place the stackview in view  with `clipsToBounds = YES` and `layer.cornerRadius = kHalfTheWidthOfTheCircleInYourExample`

The parent view will have a circular mask that clips the child image and child button.